# Base for usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I know that the set $\{(a,b):a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ forms a base for usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ but why not this set $\{[a,b]:a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$?

Comment: It *is* a so-called network for the topology, provided we always have $a<b$ in these intervals. A network is like a base * without * the requirement that all members are open.

Answer (score 5):

I you took $\{[a,b] : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ to be the basis of your topology, then in particular all of those sets would be open. So for example $[0,1]$ would be open, which is not the case in the standard topology.

Comment: Does the set {[a,b]:a,b are rational and a<b}forms a base for any topology on R?

Comment: Yes, it does. One needs to check that $A:=\{[a,b] : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}, a < b\}$ covers $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\forall [a,b], [c,d'] \in A$ and $x \in [a,b] \cap [c,d]$ there exists $[e,f] \in A$ s.t. $x \in [e,f] \subseteq [a,b] \cap [c,d]$; and this is the case here.

Comment: As an exercise, for which topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is $A$ a base?

Comment: Obviously if A forms a topology on R that will be different from usual topology. But which one it generates?

Comment: I once asked my professor that wether this set A forms a base for topology on R he said no but if the end points in A be like a is rational and b is irrational then the set A will be a bse for some topology

Comment: How can i prove it?

Comment: I think should ask that as a separate question, since the answer will take more space than a comment. Plus its customary i guess

Answer (score 3):

A base for a topology is a subcollection of the topology. Since $[a,b]$ is not open in the usual topology these sets do not form  a base.

Comment: If i use the concept that a collection of sets forms a base for usual topology on R if every open interval in R contains at least one basis element. How can i show that there does not exist any open interval in R which contain in [a,b] where a,b are rational numbers

Comment: With your definition it is true that closed intervals with rational end points form a base. But this is not an accepted definition of  a base. Do you have a reference where  a base is defined this way?  @Stewen